# 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in > Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to create sample asp.net core application. But on debug it throws an error:

> An exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Could not load type
>   'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Extensions.ServiceCollectionExtensions'
>   from assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.

what's wrong?

project.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "platform"
    }
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core": "1.0.1"` and `"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final"`, then replace it with `"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1"`

Final version

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "platform"
    }
  }
```

`Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc` already references `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core`, so there is no need to reference it directly.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions": "1.0.0" in dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Your `project.json` looks like you were using ASP.NET Core RC2, but since then you upgraded to released version.

Documentation says, that in order to make everything work in RC2 you were supposed to

> If you were targeting .NET Core with RC2, you needed to add imports to project.json as a temporary workaround for some of EF Core’s dependencies not supporting .NET Standard. These can now be removed.

Source: [ASP.NET Core documentation](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/miscellaneous/rc2-rtm-upgrade.html#net-core-remove-imports-in-project-json)

So remove

```
"imports": [
    "dotnet5.6",
    "portable-net45+win8"
]
```

from your `project.json`

Comment: You mean RC1. in RC2 all packages were already renamed to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.*`